# Vim syntax: Matching namespace qualified symbols

Tags: clojure, syntax-highlighting, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using vim-clojure-static, a Clojure plugin. I can add my own functions and macros to a syntax group by doing for example:
`syntax keyword clojureMacro defsystem`

But in Clojure, after one has required (imported) code from other namespaces, one has to namespace qualify the functions and macros. For example, if I required the namespace `my-namespace` and `defsystem` was in `my-namespace`, I would have to refer to it by `ny-namespace/defsystem`. But as one requires another namespace, one may shorten (actually rename) the namespace name, to, for example, `my/defsystem`.

So, the problem: the `syntax keyword clojureMacro defsystem` does not work if `defsystem` is namespace qulified, like `my/defsystem`. And the namespace qualifier can be anything. How can I fix that? The regex `'\m[a-z.+\-*_!?]\+\/'` matches namespace qualifiers. So basically I want code that matches `'\m[a-z.+\-*_!?]\+\/'` immediately followed by a clojureMacro, to be highlighted as if the whole thing was a clojureMacro.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really answer your question, but anyhow.

Back in the days VimClojure provided the so-called "dynamic highlighting." It would inspect the required namespaces (and their aliases) and would dynamically add the symbols of the referenced namespaces to the highlighting. So if you typed "m/defsystem" it would by highlighted, but "m/non-existant" or "not-m/defsystem" would not. The highlighting did respect being a macro or function etc. Would you ever change the namespace alias from "m" to something else, the highlighting would (almost) automatically adapt. However it needed a backend server running.

Maybe you want to ping the guys on the [vimclojure google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/vimclojure). It's all about vim and clojure. Maybe someone there is willing to lend a hand and carry over this functionality as a fireplace extension.

Comment: Hi kotarak! I assume you are pretty good at Vim stuff. So is what I'm asking not possible? Also, another question I was having while trying this out: I did for example `syntax match clojureMacro '\m\([a-z.+\-*_!?]\+\/\)\?defsystem'` Is there a way to have the regex in a variable or something else that can be evaluated, and give that as an argument instead? Something like `let nsq = '\m\([a-z.+\-*_!?]\+\/\)\?'` and then doing `syntax match clojureMacro eval(nsq . 'defsystem')` It does not work; but can it be done somehow?

Comment: It probably can be done with something like `execute "syntax match clojureMacro ". nsq . "defsystem"`. Untested however.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there still looking for a solution, I've reimplemented VimClojure's dynamic highlighting feature as a fireplace.vim plugin:

https://github.com/guns/vim-clojure-highlight